# How to manage acc in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a News Webserver where registered user can get RSS News. I want to build an iOS application use to get News from my webserver but i don't know how to manage acc in iOS application. How can i save logined user on iDevice ( store on .plis file, Core Data ....???, store real usr/pass or store encode user/pass), how can i verify stored user/pass with my Webserver? Anybody can help me :(

PS:

My current way:

In my iOS app:

```
  + User input usr+pass.


  + usr+pass send to webserver. If usr+pass is valid, webserver return token string(is encode string of usr+pass).


  + If webserver return token string, store token string into .plit file, else do notthing.
```

When user press "Get News"/

```
  + iOS send token string to webserver to verify. If valid return News of this usr acc, else return null.
```

How can i improved my current way to enhance security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is store your user's username in the applications preferences. See [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You aren't allowed to store the user's password as plain text. What you should do instead is store it in the Keychain. See this guide for more information: [Keychain Services Tasks for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html).